# Generate header only library in c++ that output a single hpp file

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

I want to write a small library in c++ then "compile" it and release it as a single .hpp file. I can't figure out an easy way to create a single .hpp file from a code base though.

I'm attempting to make something similar to catch.hpp. When I look at their code base they seem to be doing something similar. They seem to have a large collection of .h and .cpp files that are then used to generate a .hpp file.

I want my project structure to look something like the following:\

```
folder
  - src
    - something.h
    - something.cpp
    - another_thing.h
    - another_thing.cpp

  - tests
    - something_tests.cpp
    - another_thing_tests.cpp

  - console_app
     - main.cpp
```

I'd like to create a makefile and run a few commands:

`make library` => creates library.hpp containing everything in the src folder.
`make tests` => runs tests
`make console` => creates library.hpp, then compiles main.cpp in console_app folder

I generally know how to do the make tests, however I don;t understand how to create an hpp file from the src folder.

Comment: catch.hpp is generated via a script: https://github.com/log4cplus/Catch/blob/67f796495fb9ce21f0f41671b3c4f950bc0def6f/scripts/generateSingleHeader.py - which essentially just concatenates all the files together into a single file

Comment: Don't even get started with adding `.cpp` files into your header only lib. There are things usually in cpp files that must not be done in a header only lib, such as non-inline function definitions, ect that can easily result in a name conflict, if your lib is included in more than one translation unit of binary using it. Furthermore I don't see how throwing everything into a single header file is beneficial; this just makes it harder to near impossible to find stuff: noone wants to search your 50k loc file for the stuff they're looking for...

Comment: @UnholySheep This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much! I was thinking a simple script would be easier anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@UnholySheep's answer above:

> catch.hpp is generated via a script: [github.com/log4cplus/Catch/blob/…](https://github.com/log4cplus/Catch/blob/67f796495fb9ce21f0f41671b3c4f950bc0def6f/scripts/generateSingleHeader.py) which essentially just concatenates all the files together into a single file

Paired with @fabian's answer:

> Don't even get started with adding `.cpp` files into your header only lib. There are things usually in cpp files that must not be done in a header only lib, such as non-inline function definitions, ect that can easily result in a name conflict, if your lib is included in more than one translation unit of binary using it. Furthermore I don't see how throwing everything into a single header file is beneficial; this just makes it harder to near impossible to find stuff: noone wants to search your 50k loc file for the stuff they're looking for..

I've determined the best solution is to write the code in .hpp files to begin with. Then just to write a script that concatenates all of the .hpp files into a single file. The file structure will look like this:

```
folder
  - src
    - something.hpp
    - another_thing.hpp

  - tests
    - something_tests.cpp
    - another_thing_tests.cpp

  - console_app
     - main.cpp
  
  - library_gen_script.sh
```

Then the script library_gen_script.sh will just contain logic to package all of the stuff in the src folder into a single .hpp file.